# mapbox dataset api, update request with curl

Tags: php, curl, mapbox, put

I am trying to update a feature data in mapbox dataset, with datasets api PUT request. I am following their [Documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#insert-or-update-a-feature) but it always shows me "not found" response message. Below is the code I am using in my laravel function. I have successfully retrieved data for same feature_id and dataset_id with api get request but PUT request is not working.  so there is nothing wrong with credentials.

```
    $userName = 'account_user_name';
    $datasetId = 'dataset_id';
    $featureId = 'feature_id'; 
    $accessToken = 'access_token';

    $featureBody = json_encode(array(
                    'id' => '{feature_id}',
                    'type' => 'Feature',
                    'geometry' => [
                                'type' =>'point',
                                'coordinates' => [ -1.16991, 52.964993]
                      ],
                      'properties' =>  [
                        'id' => 10392,
                        'name' => 'Sharif & Sons Superstore 123',
                        'is_featured' => 'No'
                      ]
    ));


    $url = "https://api.mapbox.com/datasets/v1/{$userName}/{$datasetId}/features/{$featureId}?access_token=$accessToken";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 
                                                'Content-Length: ' . strlen($featureBody))
                                                );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$featureBody);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $json = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $arr1 = json_decode($json);

    print_r($arr1);
```

Comment: Check if your access token have the scope for datasets:write. look into access token scope. create a new access token.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the json object id be the variable $featureId, not the string '{featureId}'?

```
$featureBody = json_encode(array(
                'id' => $featureId,
                'type' => 'Feature',
                'geometry' => [
                            'type' =>'point',
                            'coordinates' => [ -1.16991, 52.964993]
                  ],
                  'properties' =>  [
                    'id' => 10392,
                    'name' => 'Sharif & Sons Superstore 123',
                    'is_featured' => 'No'
                  ]
));
```